# linear independence proposition proof Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

The proposition: Let V be a vector Space. Any set of vectors S that is a subset of V containing the zero vector is linearly independent.

The proof:  (0 being the 0 vector)
Assume S = {0,v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>,..v<sub>k</sub>}
then 10 + 0v<sub>1</sub>+..+0<sub>k</sub> = 0
S is linearly dependent.

How come we are multiplying the 0 vector by a 1 and not a 0? This seems to confuse me.

Comment: The result should say, "these vectors are linearly *dependent.*" A set of vectors $w_1, \ldots, w_k$ are linearly dependent if there exists a linear combination $a_1 w_1 + \ldots + a_k w_k = 0$ where at least one $a_i \neq 0$. Any non-zero scalar coefficient of $0$ would suffice to show that this set is linearly dependent.

Comment: I think it should be "linearly dependent".

Comment: I apologize, it was meant to be linearly dependent.

Comment: You can multiply the $\vec{0}$ vector by anything distinct than zero, and the proof goes the same. This is the definition of linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

We also have $0\cdot 0+0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2=0$, however this doesn't prove neither linear dependence nor independence since it's true for any set of vectors.

To obtain a proof for linear dependence we need coefficients *not all zero* that yields $0$ as the linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

A set $S$ is defined to be linearly dependent if there exist some scalars $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ and some vectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ in $S$ such that:

- $\lambda_1 v_1 + ... + \lambda_n v_n = 0$
- At least one of the $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ is not zero.

This is why you shouldn't take the scalar $0$ multiplying the $0$ vector, because in that case you wouldn't be showing proof of linear dependency.